# Restricting UIPanGestureRecognizer movement

Tags: ios, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIView object that can be dragged around using UIPanGestureRecognizer, but I only want it to be able to move up 3/4 of the screen. I don't want to it be clipped, but to get to a certain point and not be able to be dragged any further. What I have so far allows it to only move on the Y axis (which is desired).

```
- (IBAction)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
  CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
  recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, 
                                       recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
  [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So just check whether the new Y coordinate would be too small.  Don't change the view if it would be too small:

```
- (IBAction)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
  CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
  [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

  CGPoint center = recognizer.view.center;
  center.y += translation.y;
  if (center.y < self.yMin)
    return;
  recognizer.view.center = center;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I made yMin an int, which required `self->yMin` instead. Was this the best way of going about things?

Comment: Sounds like a fine way to do it. You can have a property that is type `int`.  You just don't declare it `retain/assign/strong/weak`.  But if you don't need to expose it as a property, you can just use an ivar.  You can access the ivar by saying `yMin`.  You don't have to say `self->yMin` unless you have a local variable also named `yMin` that you *don't* want to access.

Answer (score 2):

Its work fine for me.

```
  CGPoint currentTouchPoint = [gesture translationInView:self.bottomView];

    if (fabsf(currentTouchPoint.x) > fabsf(currentTouchPoint.y))    {
        // avoid horizontal movement of pan geuture.
        return;
    }
```

thanks,

Naveen Shan

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following gesture delegate and check your condition inside it. Returning YES or NO from this delegate will make the gesture active and inactive.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```